# rollback transcation failing when inside sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have seen a lot of peripheral information relating to my problem, but nothing directly on point. I have some code which refreshes views, but sometimes the views have become invalid because someone somewhere has broken a dependency or whatnot. I need to delete any such invalid views.  The main part of my code works fine and looks like this (all variable and cursor definitions left out for space considerations):

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
    EXEC sp_refreshview @view
    PRINT @view
    COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH     -- If the view can't be refreshed, it's because it's invalid.  Delete it.  
    PRINT 'deleting invalid view: recorded error in this refreshView on : ' + @view
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION T1
    SET @drop_view_command = N'DROP VIEW ' + @view;
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @drop_view_command
END CATCH;
```

And of course this code is inside a while loop with a cursor, and all variables are correctly defined up top. So far so good. However, I need to run this code from inside a bigger script with it's own transaction. So I wrap this code inside it's own `sp_executesql` call as such.

```
IF (@errval = 0)
    BEGIN
    EXEC @errval = sys.sp_executesql @stmt = N'
    --previous code in here, with quotes correctly escaped
    '
END
```

When I do, it fails with

> Cannot roll back T1. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.

I am not some expert DB developer; is there something goofy about nested transactions that I am not getting here? Why would the code work fine on it's own, but not inside the `sp_executesql` call?

I'm running SQL Server 2008.

Oh, I also have the luxury of being able to run this script during down time, so I don't need to worry about any other users on while this gets run.

**EDITED:**  After a lot of research, it seems this problem has to do with that nested transactions are not really supported in SQL server.  My ROLLBACK in the catch block would roll back the entire calling script with it's own transaction, which is not at all what I want to do.  I want to just delete the view that caused the problem and merrily continue on my way.  This is why the code works in isolation, but not when being called from within another transaction calling sp_executesql.

I tried to find a way to catch the error on sp_refreshview in some other way, but apparently it sets XACT_STATE = -1, which means I am just doomed.

Any clever ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, since sp_refreshview is a transaction killer, and nested transactions don't really work as expected, the answer was to change the sp_refreshview call to something that would throw a catchable error.  I offer this solution here for anyone else who might run into this.

This code runs successfully, whether on it's own, or from within a larger transaction called by sp_executesql.

```
BEGIN TRY
    SET @statement = 'SELECT * INTO #view_temp FROM + ' @view + ' WHERE 1 = 2'
    EXEC @exec_err = sp_executesql @stmt = @statement
    PRINT 'Refreshing view ' + @view
    EXEC sp_refreshview @view
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'deleting invalid view: recorded error in this refreshView on : ' + @view
    SET @drop_view_command = N'DROP VIEW ' + @view;
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @drop_view_command
END CATCH
```